# In sqlplus ttitle displays error

Tags: sqlplus

I am using ttitle left 'blabla' in some SQL file between `spool` and `spool off` to display some title in generated files inside SQLPlus.

Sometimes it works and sometimes it throws this:

```
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning 'left 'blabla' - rest of line ignored.
```

Any ideas what the problem might be?

I thought about file conversion between DOS and UNIX but it is not that.

Thank you

Exemple of code

```
spool $P_LOG/Amia_Autr
clear columns
column  ident   format a40    heading  'Identifiant'
column  montant  heading  'Montant     '
column montant  format  B999999,99
column euro heading ' '
column  modpai  heading  'Mode de paiement'
column  today   noprint new_value datejour 

ttitle left _nomregion skip 2 -
   left 'Edition du ' FORMAT DATE datejour skip 1 -
   left 'Application AGATA ' _numvers ' de ' FORMAT DATE _datvers skip 3 -
   left '         LISTE DES ALLOCATAIRES NON PAYES PAR VIREMENT' skip 1 - 
   left '         =============================================' skip 3 -
   left 'Echéance du ' FORMAT DATE _dtech skip 3 

select ......

ttitle off
set heading off
select 'Fin de la liste des allocataires non payes par virement' from dual;
set heading on
spool off
```

Comment: What actually your code looks like? Can we see some excerpt?